# How to send several requests in turn in a loop js

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, fetch

I need to send a request every time after the end of the previous request from the loop. but i can't do it through async/await. Please help.

```
    genQuote = () => {
    let quotes = [{quote: 1},{quote: 2}...{quote: n}]

    quotes.map(async (simple,i) => {
      await this.sendSimple(simple)
    }).then(()=>{console.log('Done ' + i)}))
  }

  sendSimple = (simple) => {
    request('rest/api', {
      method: 'POST',,
      body: JSON.stringify(simple)
    })
  }
```

Comment: `return this.sendSimple(simple);` and `return request('rest/api', ...)` Your functions need to return promises for await to do anything interesting.

Comment: Try not to mix async/await with .then().catch()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `for...of` if you want it to wait before running the next iteration.

```
   async function genQuote() {
    let quotes = [{quote: 1},{quote: 2}...{quote: n}];

     for (let quote of quotes) {
      await this.sendSimple(simple);
    }

    console.log('All Done');

  }
```

But you will also need the sendSimple function to return a `Promise`.

Answer (score 1):

sendSimple has to return a promise for you to use async, await. You also cant use await inside a map like that. Unless you wanna fire all of them at the same time using Promise.all, just use a loop. Something like this should do the trick:

```
    async genQuote = () => {
      let quotes = [{ quote: 1 }, { quote: 2 }...{ quote: n }]
      for (let i = 0; i < quotes.length; i++){
        await this.sendSimple(simple);
        console.log('Done ' + i)
      }
    }


async sendSimple = (simple) => {
   new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request('rest/api', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(simple)
        })
            .then(resolve)
            .catch(err => reject(err))
    })
}
```

Comment: Should be .then(resolve) without the parentheses in case the calling code wants to do something with the results.

Comment: Also, you should remove the async/await used in sendSimple, they're not needed.